# Compiling error

Tags: compiling

Hi I need to run some tests with a  [CP ABE toolkit I've found](http://acsc.cs.utexas.edu/cpabe/), I'm a total newbie of Linux, I've started using for a few days, so please bear with me. 
I've found [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXDQ1J8kRw0) that was quite helpful which made me install:
-m4 macro processing language
-gmp library
-pbc library
-libcrypt
-libssl
-libglib2.0
-libbswabe library

I've followed every single passage of the video, but when I have to compile the cpabe package after the make this error pops up (while it doesn't seem the case in the tutorial)

```
~/Downloads/cpabe-0.11$ make
gcc -c -o setup.o setup.c -O3 -Wall -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pbc -I/usr/local/include/pbc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"cpabe\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"cpabe\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.11\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"cpabe\ 0.11\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bethenco@cs.berkeley.edu\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_H=1 -DHAVE_STDDEF_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DLSTAT_FOLLOWS_SLASHED_SYMLINK=1 -DHAVE_VPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_LIBCRYPTO=1 -DHAVE_LIBCRYPTO=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_GMP=1 -DHAVE_PBC=1 -DHAVE_BSWABE=1
gcc -c -o common.o common.c -O3 -Wall -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pbc -I/usr/local/include/pbc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"cpabe\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"cpabe\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.11\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"cpabe\ 0.11\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"bethenco@cs.berkeley.edu\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_H=1 -DHAVE_STDDEF_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DLSTAT_FOLLOWS_SLASHED_SYMLINK=1 -DHAVE_VPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_LIBCRYPTO=1 -DHAVE_LIBCRYPTO=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_GMP=1 -DHAVE_PBC=1 -DHAVE_BSWABE=1
common.c: In function ‘suck_file’:
common.c:137:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fread(a->data, 1, s.st_size, f);
  ^
common.c: In function ‘read_cpabe_file’:
common.c:211:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fread((*aes_buf)->data, 1, len, f);
  ^
common.c:218:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fread((*cph_buf)->data, 1, len, f);
  ^
gcc -o cpabe-setup setup.o common.o -O3 -Wall -lglib-2.0 -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lgmp -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lpbc -lbswabe -lcrypto -lcrypto 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpbc.so: undefined reference to symbol '__gmpz_init'
/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'cpabe-setup' failed
make: *** [cpabe-setup] Error 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the Makefile and find the following lines :

```
LDFLAGS = -O3 -Wall \
        -lglib-2.0   \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lgmp \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lpbc \
        -lbswabe \
        -lcrypto -lcrypto
```

Now just add a `-lgmp` beside `-lcrypto` and it will be successful

```
LDFLAGS = -O3 -Wall \
        -lglib-2.0   \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lgmp \
        -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib -lpbc \
        -lbswabe \
        -lcrypto -lcrypto -lgmp
```